# iOS Collection View Lagging

Tags: swift, image, uicollectionview, responsiveness

In my App I am using a CollectionView to display some Images. When I start scrolling performance is quite poor and big lags occur. I tried utilising an Image cache so the Images are not reloaded every time the cell appears. I have also tried removing the rounded edges and utilising layer.shouldRasterize. Nothing seems to help. The Images are in the Assets of the App.

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
```

...

```
class MainMenuController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ....
}




//Collection View
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MainMenuCell


    cell.titleLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item].getName()
    cell.titleLabel.textColor = ColorInterface.sharedInstance.ultra_textcolor

    if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: items[indexPath.item].getKey() as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
        cell.imageView.image = imageFromCache
    }
    else
    {
        let imageToCache = UIImage(named: items[indexPath.item].getImage())!
        imageCache.setObject(imageToCache, forKey: items[indexPath.item].getKey() as AnyObject)
        cell.imageView.image = imageToCache
    }

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 7

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let totalHeight: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.width / 2)
    let totalWidth: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.width / 2)

    return CGSize(width: ceil(totalWidth - 5),height: ceil(totalHeight - 5))
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    for index in indexPaths
    {
        if imageCache.object(forKey: items[index.item].getKey() as AnyObject) == nil
        {
            let imageToCache = UIImage(named: items[index.item].getImage())!
            imageCache.setObject(imageToCache, forKey: items[index.item].getKey() as AnyObject)
        }
    }
}
}
```

After I scrolled to the bottom once everything is silky smooth which originally lead me to believing it is the loading of the images which is causing problems. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Show the code for the `getImage` function

Comment: How big are the images in pixels?

Comment: The getImage function just returns the name of the Image that is supposed to be shown: ´public func getImage() -> String { return Image }´. The Images are 500x500px in size.

Comment: Did you try to load images asynchronize ?

Comment: Do you mean setting the image via DispatchQueue.main,aysnc ?